# How does 4 pole single coil motor move?

Tags: dc-motor

When there is just 2 field poles, the coil dipole moves to align with the external magnetic field. So a torque is produced.

However when there there are 4 field poles, why will the coil dipole move? From the below picture it seems the armature coil will not rotate no matter the starting position...

[image]

Comment: Be careful when looking at simple motor diagrams. They are often made to solely to illustrate a concept, and not represent how a real machine is actually built.

Comment: Commutation is twice as often (not shown in your simple diagram).

Comment: @DKNguyen Ty. Ofcourse... I get the brushes and commutator part in a 2 pole single coil motor. The field poles are mostly permanent magnets and the armature can be made up of many coils. I feel I understand it well. I don't see how the torque is produced in 4 pole single coil armature..

Comment: @Andyaka oh do you mean the commutator will have 4 breaks instead of just 2(as shown in the picture)?

Comment: Yes I do mean that.

Comment: They are called commutator segments. Is that what you didn't realize?

Comment: @Andyaka so a simple single coil armature will not work with 4 field poles. From symmetry I feel the diagonal poles in the armature need to be same. Then only a net torque will be produced. I'll read some more on lap/wave winding and get back:) These do look scary! Always good to see you here XD